# Requesting switch from on-site to remote

Tags: software-industry, telecommute

I've been with my current company for about 7 months as a full stack developer. I'm planning to discuss the option of moving from on-site to remote work in the beginning of September as I'm trying to live with my girlfriend ~2.5 hours away (long standing plan, very important to both of us). We already work with a remote team (not just contractors, full time employees), as well as remote workers for the remote team (also living ~2.5 hours from our remote office). How should I bring up this request to my boss? I would be able to commute in for special events & important meetings, just not in a daily routine.

Comment: You could suggest a trial period and make sure it actually shows a productivity improvement, but IMHO you should be prepared to look for a new job.

Comment: Welcome to the site @telecommuting_guest! Have you taken a look at this question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/195/how-should-i-bring-up-working-from-home ?

Comment: Just to confirm - you are a contract employee on a contract team, and your team works for a client? So you have a boss on your contracting company as well as a client manager (of sorts)?

Comment: @ 1st comment, I'm afraid of the latter, but I think I have a solid argument for the former. Good suggestion with the trial period. @ 2nd comment, that's a great link, thanks! Didn't see it when searching earlier. @ 3rd comment, I'm a full time hired employee working on-site for my employer. We have a remote office of other full-time employees. My boss' boss is the CTO, the remote office only has developers who are unable to work on-site.

Comment: @telecommuting_guest use @<username> to refer to someone's post, it also results in a notification for that user. Welcome to the Stack exchange network.